# Slow internet connection requires forced reset of network adapter?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, device-manager

Computer is connected directly to modem via ethernet. Upon boot, an online speed test is consistently 10 Mb/s. This is significantly less than my service is supposed to be (50+). As soon as I disable and enable the ethernet adapter I can run another speed test at 60+ Mb/s. The connection appears to be stable at this point.

Additional information: Ethernet adapter is Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller. Drivers are up to date. Tried rolling back drivers. Tried an old modems. Tried flushing DNS, resetting winsock, resetting IP. Tried changing the adapters speed from auto negotiation to 100 full.

I've got nothing. For the time being I've just got a batch file (using devmanview.exe) that resets the adapter on delay after boot but I'd like a more elegant solution. I've had hilarious conversations with my ISP support where I realize this is no longer on their script so they're no help.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon a fix. Turns out the power output to wifi in my router settings was set to 100%. On a whim, I turned this down to 75%. This didn't seem to effect the wifi performance elsewhere in the house but it made my ethernet adapter resolve the connection speed correctly and perform more reliably.

The router is a Motorola Surfboard modem/router combo.